# How to check if the email is valid?

Tags: email

I have a list of email ids. some bounce. i wanna know how i can weed out the once which dont exists.

any software which helps us do it ?

Comment: We (users) don't want you to do this.

Comment: Yes, the ones that bounce should be weed out.

Comment: This isn't a programming question.  It's a request for techniques and possibly existing software.

Comment: You (users) will then never be notified why you are not receiving your important notifications anymore. If the server detects bounces, at least you can get a notification in your user account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, pretty much all email servers will refuse to tell you if an address is valid or not these days since otherwise it would be abused by spammers.

Answer (score 2):

Verification links are the only way

Comment: +1 because I can prevent spam by not clicking the link. The address can still go away later though.

Answer (score 2):

Detect the bounces and remove the addresses that bounce from your list. There is no other way, and the overhead is neglectable.

Answer (score 2):

Send an email to each of them. If you don't get a bounce back then the email is probably valid.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Max Prog for this problem before.

http://www.maxprog.com/site/misc/products_us.php

Answer (score 1):

Here is a boolean function that you can put in your JavaScript to check weather the emails are valid (this regex has a ~95% success rate):

```
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) 
{    
    var emailPattern = new RegExp(/^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@([a-z0-9_][-a-z0-9_]*(\.[-a-z0-9_]+)*\.(aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro|travel|mobi|[a-z][a-z])|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$/i);
    return emailPattern.test(emailAddress);
}
```

Note that this does not check whether they exist or not, but will help in weeding out false emails.