# How to check email exist in php

Tags: php, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if the email is valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470373/how-to-check-if-the-email-is-valid)

- How can we check validate email?
- How can we check if email address really exist in php?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470373/how-to-check-if-the-email-is-valid?rq=1

Comment: Validate using the loosest possible regular expression and then **send an email to the address**. That is the only way.

Comment: What do you mean by `email exists`? Exists where?

Comment: to validate email format you could use `filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`, but by `email exist`, do you mean exist as an actual email or somewhere in the database?

Comment: I want to know email address is really exist or not? for example: abc@aaa.com, if we just write down but it not available this email with domain: aaa.com

Comment: Then send an email to the address. As I said: It is the only way. There is no magic method for telling whether an email address exists.

Comment: @Nemoden guess he means, DNS - if this one exists

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to validate email just use type="email"

Example

```
<form>
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: surely `HTML5` is not the answer to everything.

Answer (score 1):

```
filter_var('test@test.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```